# What module or views recipe can display a featured node with different layouts from the rest?

Tags: views, theming, entities

I'm building out a views layout where I need to display a featured node with a different layout from the rest of the nodes being displayed. It looks something like this:

[image]

As you can see the middle node is larger than the rest and has body content displayed. What methods are there to output a custom views layout like this?

Comment: may be including another view into header?

Comment: This looks like a job for _drumroll_ Display Suite + Views!!!

Comment: yea but how do you display only a "featured" node while everything else is not a featured. sure i can make 2 views one for the featured and the other one as regular. but was wondering if there was a quicker way by selecting an option somewhere.

Comment: Like @tenken recommends, Display Suite has the feature to render different view modes for the first 10 rows out of the box, and provides for you to extend it to something completely custom.

Comment: link for the lazy http://clikfocus.com/blog/changing-views-output-based-row like the 4th google result. as an alternative the blog post covers this module as well https://www.lullabot.com/blog/article/module-monday-views-nodes-split ... but i prefer to stick with DS as site-wide it's more powerful once learned.

Answer (score 0):

Seem that you can go with the module called **views_nodes_split** https://www.drupal.org/project/views_nodes_split

**BUT, this is better solution if your using display suite already:**
You can just use Display Suite + Views as there is a setting when choosing an output. Display suite lets you pick which view mode to use for each output:

[image]